# Foreground extraction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv, parallax, feature-extraction

I have a very 'simple' photo, with a Face plus Background.
I want to create a software (in Javascript) that detects face/background.
In this scenario we can create a kind of Parallax effect by animating them.

Can you have experience in that? Is it possible?

After a lot of research, i have only found GrabCut.
But as I know it isn't 100% accurate.

Comment: ah, don't reinvent the [wheel](https://github.com/liuliu/ccv/tree/unstable/js)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible e.g. using a JavaScript [face detector](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect#performance) and [histogram backprojection](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_backprojection/py_histogram_backprojection.html).

1. Detect the face and create a model histogram of that region.
2. Use histogram backprojection to assign each pixel around the face the probability of belonging to our model, i.e. face.
3. Use thresholding for foreground - background separation.

Here is an example output of that process for pupil extraction using [js-objectdetect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect) and the histogram backprojection algorithm from [headtrackr](https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr):

[image]